# Should I include the second had in "Had he died like Nietzsche **had** declared?"

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

> Even without a speck of cloud, I couldn’t spot God. Had he died like
>   Nietzsche **had** said/declared?

(This is first-person narration past tense. And Nietzsche, a dead philosopher, said that statement centuries ago.)

Do I need the **second** had? Why or why not.

Comment: If it's looking deeper into the past before "**death**" then I'd add the second "**had**" there.

Comment: This is more a matter of perspective. The second *had* is optional there.

Comment: What @Robusto said. But from *my* perspective, it seems better *not* to include it in the specific cited context (within which I'd also change ***like*** to *comma + **as***).

Comment: Thank you for letting us know that Nietzsche was a philosopher, and especially for the good news that he is dead.

Comment: You could say *Was He dead as Nietzsche had declared?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks, what the difference with starting the sentence with "Had ...?"

Comment: In terms of grammar: **was** takes a subject complement (predicate adjective).  **had** is an auxiliary that combines with the past participle of the verb to form a past perfect. In your case you have three times (the spotting, the declaring, the dying) and the spotting is already in the past tense, which creates the very issue you're asking about: how to handle the past perfect in a three-time scenario. My advice is to take the dying out of the equation and make it into a simple *state* (was dead) current as of the time of the spotting, rather than an *event-in-time-resulting-in-a-state*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order too fully determine whether the second "**had**" is necessary, you may need to finish the context of your sentence.

> **Had** he died like Nietzsche **had** said *(when / about what)*?

The sentence *sounds heavy* with two "**had**"s

If your intention is complete, then it might be phrased as

> Is he dead like Nietsche **said**?
>   Had he died like Nietsche **said**?

*simple past* which is still *currently* true.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. **Declared** here is a  *past simple* verb that limits previous action in *past perfect* **he had died**. So in this sentence you have two tenses: *past perfect* **Had he died** and *past simple* **Nietzsche said/declared**. And grammatically it means that **God died** before **Nietzsche said** that.

Adding second **had** you'd have to add something in past simple to limit past perfect. Because past perfect is used to talk about something that happened before another action in the past. And that's the case we have here.

And besides, having two *past perfects* will change the meaning of the sentence. It'll mean that actions **Had he died** and **Nietzsche had said/declared** had occurred before another action in the past but without clear indication which action happened earlier: **Had he died** or **Nietzsche had said/declared**

So adding another **had** will be grammatically incorrect here.